# What is accord.net's HOG actually returning?

Tags: c#, .net, computer-vision, accord.net

I'm using aforge.net's HistogramsOfOrientedGradients class to get the histogram of a 64x128 grayscale image. Calling the ProcessImage method I get a list of 8 arrays, each of length 144. The HOG object was initialised with the following parameters:

```
HistogramsOfOrientedGradients hog = new HistogramsOfOrientedGradients(numberOfBins: 9, blockSize: 4, cellSize: 8);
```

Could anyone explain what this result is? Where do 8 and 144 come from? Are these the vectors of the 9 bins before block normalization? 
    Unfortunately the documentation doesn't reveal anything useful about the results.
    I read the paper by Dalal and Triggs but I must confess that it's a little hard to digest.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out, just in case anyone else comes across this:

As per [this dirty sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcZtE.jpg), a block size of 4 (green box) with cell sizes of 8 gives us 8 blocks (in other words 8 green boxes) in total over the entire 64*128 image. 
Each block contains 16 histograms (red boxes), therefore we get 8 arrays of 16*9 = 144 length.